# AntD custom color for active tab without css/less,

Tags: reactjs, tabs, antd

I am trying to change the background color for the active tab from AntD tabs, I can achieve that with **less** file by targeting:

```
.ant-tabs-tab.ant-tabs-tab-active .ant-tabs-tab-btn {
  color: blue;
}
```

so that is not a problem, my problem is that I need to change the background color of the active tab based on javascript condition and I am not sure how to target the active tab with javascript and **without css/less**.

Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element, using the querySelector function(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```
 const Demo = () => {
    function callback(key) {
    updateTabBackground();
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
   updateTabBackground();
  }, []);

  const updateTabBackground = () => {
    const tab = document.querySelector('[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]');
    console.log(tab)

    if(tab) {
      tab.style.background = 'red';
    }
  }
        
  return (
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
          <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
            Content of Tab Pane 1
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
            Content of Tab Pane 2
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
            Content of Tab Pane 3
          </TabPane>
      </Tabs>)
          
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to follow your example but it seems like the const tab is equal to null (I console.log tab and I got null).

Comment: Where are you testing this example?

Comment: Thanks again, this is not working as it should, it changes the background color of the content in the tab and not all tab itself, and also it changes the previously selected tab and not the current one, I made an example in code sendbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-northcutt-nibhq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I updated the code  here https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-frost-i6k07?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response!
That is working well, but it is actually not cover my need, I am sorry maybe I was not clear, I create another sandbox with your code, and what I want actually that if machines object if the machine marked as urgent the tab will be in a different color, here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cdn-e4izl?file=/src/App.js:0-1365

Comment: Do you want  to change the background color for the active tab marked as urgent? or change the color to all tabs marked as urgent, no matter if it is active?

Comment: So I want to change 2 things:
1. To change the color of the active color lets say to blue.
2. Change the color of the urgent order red even if it is the tab is active or not - but it should be red always.

Comment: Just add tabItem.classList.add(data[i].urgent && "ant-tab-urgent"); inside for loop, https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-pond-0lkwf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use css/less, you can just use inline styles:

```
let style = {};

if (condition) style.color = 'red';

return <Component style={style} />
```

But you can also do it (a little more cleanly in my opinion) by adding a class based on a condition in JavaScript and handle the styling in css/less:

```
let class;

if (condition) class = 'specialClass';

return <Component className={class} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am aware of this approach, but I am still not sure how to target the active tab just with JS, so in your example, you are targeting component, but I need to target the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try some css variable to update active color from the js code.

```
const element = document.documentElement;
if (element) {
    element.style.setProperty('--active_tab_color', 'red'); // Use Dynamic color variable here.
}
```

and then go to your css file and use that variable there.

```
.ant-tabs .ant-tabs-nav-list .ant-tabs-ink-bar  {
    background-color: var(--active_tab_color);
}
```